# Function: Not getting correct answer?

Tags: matlab, function

I'm noticing something very strange about a function I'm trying to write. My code is as follows:

```
function y=testfun(x)
for i=1:2
    A(i*ones(2,2))=eye(2,2);

    y=zeros(2,2);
    y=y+eye(2,2); %+A(1*ones(2,2))
end
end
```

*If* I use `y=y+eyes(2,2)`, then I'll get that `testfun(some random number)=[1 0; 0 1]`. But if I delete `y=y+eyes(2,2)` and type, instead, `y=y+A(1*ones(2,2)), testfun(some random number) = [1 1; 1 1]`. However, I would expect to get the same answer as before, [1 0; 0 1].

Is there any chance someone might know why this is? One other question I have is this: If I type `A(1*ones(2,2))` in the command window, why is it that I get the error: *"Undefined function 'A' for input arguments of type 'double'."* Haven't I defined it?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: A is defined in your function, not in your workspace, that is why the 2nd question is an error.

Comment: Your code does not make sense in some sections. I don't get why you are doing `A(i*ones(2,2))=eye(2,2);`!! This line simply acts as `A=eye(2,2);` does.  Moreover, you do not need `x` input variable. Because you do not use it in your function.  The last thing, I don't get what do you mean by `testfun(some random number)=[1 0; 0 1]`. You cannot allocate a function to a value or matrix! since a function is a rvalue.

Comment: @Mohammad `A(i*ones(2,2))=eye(2,2)` is not the same as `A=eye(2,2);`. See my answer.

Comment: Oops! You're right @LuisMendo. I forgot that indexing thing!!

Answer (score 0):

First thing: Matlab stores elements in [column-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order). So in the first iteration (when `i` equals `1`), the line

```
A(i*ones(2,2)) = eye(2,2);
```

is equivalent to the following statements, in this order:

```
A(i) = 1;
A(i) = 0;
A(i) = 0;
A(i) = 1;
```

Of course only the last statement is effective. So in the first iteration `A` is just `1`. For the same reason, in the second iteration (when `i` equals `2`) `A(2)` is assigned a `1` and thus `A` becomes `[1 1]`.

The value of `y` returned by the function is that of the second iteration. In that iteration, consider the statement

```
y = y + A(1*ones(2,2));
```

Since `1*ones(2,2)` is just four `1`'s, the expression `A(1*ones(2,2))` is a matrix of four `1`'s, that is, `ones(2,2)`. You are adding that to the previous value of `y`, which is `zeros(2,2)`. So `y` becomes `ones(2,2)`, and that value is returned by the function.